# Wrong path when execute a remote script on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, filepath

I'm using PyCharm to programming in my raspberry pi. Then, I set it up the deployment:

[image]
[image]

And, I also set up the debug to work with remote interpreter

[image]

In my raspberry, I can see my scripts in the directory that I set, `/home/pi/foo`:

```
pi@penelo:~/foo $ pwd
/home/pi/foo
pi@penelo:~/foo $ ls
main.py  TestClass.py
```

But, when I run debug in PyCharm, it try to execute script in `/tmp/pycharm_project_967` on raspberry, instead of `/home/pi/foo`.

```
ssh://pi@192.168.15.15:22/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 42609 --file /tmp/pycharm_project_967/main.py
bash: line 0: cd: /tmp/pycharm_project_967: No such file or directory
```

Why? How to set the PyCharm to execute script at `/home/pi/foo/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. When I created this project, I set up wrongly the configuration `Remote project location`.

I used the default value, instead of `/home/pi/foo`.

[image]